# Laptop Can't connect to home wifi

Tags: drivers, wireless, laptop, atheros

I have a `Qualcom Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter` on a Samsung laptop and running 14.04.

My laptop can see the wireless network, but it keeps asking for the password and I can't connect. I know for a fact that it's not my router because my phone can connect and so can my tablet.

I have Wireless N only running on 20 MHz.

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```